# lightning:input field not passing value?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-inputfield, checkbox

I've built a form in my lightning component and it seems to be working perfectly, except for a single lightning:select field not passing thru. If I check the box in the form, it doesn't reflect that upon record creation. And I checked the debug logs and it is the only field that doesn't show..

cmp code-

```
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2" >
                <div class="slds-wrap" >
                    <span class="slds-checkbox slds-checkbox_standalone">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="1035Exchange">1035 Exchange</label>
                        <lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="1035Exchange"  name="1035Exchange" value="{!v.newLLCRPP.X1035_Exchange__c}" />        
                    </span>   
                </div>
            </div>
```

helper code (remember all of these work and push properly, except the checkbox (1035 Exchange)-

```
        myLLCRPP.push({'sobjectType': 'Proposed_Purchase__c',
                   'Add_to_Contract__c' : newLLCRPP.Add_to_Contract__c,
                   'Product__c': newLLCRPP.Product__c,                
                   'Target_Premium__c': newLLCRPP.Target_Premium__c,
                   'Plan_Premium__c': newLLCRPP.Plan_Premium__c,
                   'Name_of_Finance_Company__c': newLLCRPP.Name_of_Finance_Company__c,
                   'Premium_Generated__c': newLLCRPP.Premium_Generated__c,
                   'Premium_Finance_Info__c': newLLCRPP.Premium_Finance_Info__c,
                   'X1035_Exchange__c': newLLCRPP.X1035_Exchange__c,
                   'Financial_Objectives__c': newLLCRPP.Financial_Objectives__c,
                  });
```

debug log-
[image]

Any ideas why this is happening? I am confident the field's API name is `X1035_Exchange__c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refering to the documentation of [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleInputCheckbox)
for checkbox value is stored not in the `value` property, but int the `checked`

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Basic option" name="input1"/>
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Required option" name="input2" checked="true" required="true"/>
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Disabled option" name="input3" checked="true" disabled="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

you will need the following code:

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="1035Exchange"  name="1035Exchange" checked="{!v.newLLCRPP.X1035_Exchange__c}" />
```

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks!